# Сравнение int с char

Tags: c

Имеется функция fgetc, которая возвращает считанный символ в форме int, хотелось бы сравнить каждый полученный символ с точкой и "\n". Я в программирование и в си разбираюсь очень слабо, так что могу спросить какую-нибудь глупость или не понять очевидных вещей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну а что сложного в том что бы написать `if(((char)fgetc()) == '\n')`   ?

---

---

---

**UPD**

**про кодировки:**

как известно процессору неведомы символы и строки. Все символы всех языков хранятся в виде чисел, то есть **а,б,в**  представляются числами **1,2,3**, соответствие буквы и цифры называется **кодировка**, этих кодировок очень много и где то одна и та же буква обозначается разными числами, отсюда и растут все проблемы с "крокозябрами".

скорее всего у вас кодировка [`ASCII`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) или её расширенная версия `KOI8`

пример:

```
//вот так можно записать точку (везде символ один и тот же)
char ch='.';//записываем непосредственно символ
char ch=46;//записываем код символа в десятеричной системе
char ch=056;//записываем код символа в восьмеричной системе
char ch=0x2E;//записываем код символа в шестнадцатеричной системе
```

---

**про приведение типов:**

есть явное и неявное приведение типов

```
int i=46;
char ch1=i;//неявное
char ch2=(char) i;//явное
```

так же неявное приведение происходит при выполнении операций +,-,*,/,=,==

```
(long int) + (int) = (long int)


int i=46;
char ch='.';
if(i==ch)//тут ch приводится к int
if(i=='.')//тут '.' приводится к char, а затем к int
if(ch==46)//тут 46 и ch приводятся к int
```

на самом деле мы имеем один байт 
**`X=0010 1110`** (число 46) и указываем как его прочитать если **`(char)X`** то получим точку, если **`(int)X`** то получим 46. При этом  если мы приводим char(1 байт) к int(4 байта) лишние биты заполняются нулями(unsigned) или единицами(signed), а если приводим int(4 байта) к char(1 байт) то лишние биты отбрасываются.

Так же привидение типов работает при передаче\возврате значения в\из функцию.

---

Ну и подводя итог если вы напишите: `if(fgetc() == '.')` то слева будет int, а справа будет неявное приведение '.' к `char` а затем к `int`

Comment: >ну а что сложного в том что бы написать if(((char)fgetc() == '\n') ?

вот это:

>Я в программирование и в си разбираюсь очень слабо

 по вашему не является веской причиной?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, лучше бы объяснили новичку, **почему (с какой целью)** `fgetc()` возвращает `int` и почему можно сравнивать `char` с `int` **без приведения типа**.

Вот так 

    if (fgetc(stdin) == '\n')

и даже так

    int c;
      ...
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) == '\n'); // пропустим несколько идущих подряд '\n'
    switch (c) {
    case EOF:
      ...
    case '\t':
    case ' ':
      ...
    case 128:
      ...

тоже будет работать правильно без всякого *явного* приведения типа.

Comment: @avp  @DreamChild подправил пост

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, вот это

     если мы приводим char(1 байт) к int(4 байта) лишние биты заполняются нулями

**неверно**. На самом деле при присваивании `int` значения `char` "лишние биты" заполняются *знаковым* битом `char`. А вот для `unsigned char` - нулями.

Смотрите:

    char c = 255;
    int i = (unsigned char)c;
    uint32_t ui = c;
    printf ("ui = %x  i = %d\n", ui, i); // ui = ffffffff  i = 255

Вы спросите, почему же `case 128:` в моем примере правильно?

Это потому, что `int fgetc(FILE *);` из `libio.h` возвращает 

     *(unsigned char *) (_fp)->_IO_read_ptr++)

Answer (score -1):

> про приведение типов:
>
> есть явное и неявное приведение типов

Про приведение типов:

```
int i=46;
char ch='.';//неявное приведение к чар, нету никаких чаров.
if(i==ch)//тут ch приводится к int
if(i=='.')//тут '.' приводится к char, а затем к int//Нет, тут никаких чаров нет, ибо '.' - это инт.
if(ch==46)//тут 46 и ch приводятся к int
```

В сишке нет никаких чаров - это плюсовое, а мифы и легенды берутся из курсов С/С++. '*' - это инт, который автоматом кастится в чар, когда ты его юзает на чар.

Никакие типы приводить в сишке не надо - надо, если ты подразумеваешь под чем-то не то, что оно по дефолту, но для этого есть "суфиксы". Длинные типы в короткие кастятся спокойно - это обычная, легальная фича в ЯП - такая же, как нерабочий void * в плюсах.

Comment: @superhackkiller1997 

буду краток: просто коперну ту часть что вы не удосужились прочитать

---------------------------------
на самом деле мы имеем один байт X=0010 1110 (число 46) и указываем как его прочитать если (char)X то получим точку, если (int)X то получим 46. При этом если мы приводим char(1 байт) к int(4 байта) лишние биты заполняются нулями, а если приводим int(4 байта) к char(1 байт) то лишние биты отбрасываются.



---------------------------

Comment: Хм, подловили.

Comment: @superhackkiller1997 какой-то бред. "Значащие биты"? Ужас. Кстати:

     . '*' - это инт, который автоматом кастится в чар, когда ты его юзает на чар.

Вопрос на засыпку: чему равно `sizeof '*'` ?